# How to hide label(markup) If the textfield is hidden?

Tags: javascript, textbox, show-hide

I am using this javascript to hide the label if textbox is hidden. There are some triggers that hide textbox in some cases and there is a textlabel(just an info for textbox) but textlabel is independent from textbox-It is id name is post. How ever when textbox is hidden label is still there.

```
<script>
var query1 = $('#edit-contact-1-address-postal-code'); 
var isVisible1 = query1.is(':hidden'); 

if (isVisible1 === true) {
$('#post').hide();
}

</script>
```

Comment: could you post your html also

Comment: There is no html It is online development tool similar to wordpress

Comment: Whatever tool/framework it is you are using, it would be rendering html in the browser. Can you share your html snippet from there. You can use `inspect element` feature of chrome/firefox to see the html or just view source code in your browser.